# Retrofit 2 with RxJava2 and plain null responses error

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java2

I use [RxJava2 extension with Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2).

**RxJava2** observers doesn't support omitting **`null`** in `onNext` function.

When I call the webservice with mistaken input or anything goes wrong on the webservice, I get plain `null` as response.

Which, I think, then passed as **`null`** to rx2 observable.

This is the error i get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Null is not a valid element
        at io.reactivex.internal.queue.SpscLinkedArrayQueue.offer(SpscLinkedArrayQueue.java:68)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.onNext(ObservableObserveOn.java:116)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.onNext(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:63)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onNext(BodyObservable.java:51)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onNext(BodyObservable.java:37)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:43)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10179)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10179)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$1.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:39)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

How to solve such problem from occurring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Observable you can use Completable , which allow no response request.

EDIT:

Maybe you can use the [Map](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) operator to checking if the value is null or not, and sent a default value in this case.

```
Observable<MyClass> observable = myRetrofitService().map(new Function<MyClass, MyClass>() {
            @Override public MyClass apply(MyClass o) throws Exception {
                if (o == null) {
                    return defaultO;
                }
                return o;
            }
        });
```

if you don't care about emit a value, maybe you can use Filter operator :

```
Observable<MyClass> observable = myRetrofitService().filter(new Predicate<MyClass>() {
            @Override public boolean test(MyClass o) throws Exception {
                return o != null;
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: @yosriz Let me know if it's solved your issue or if you have some questions

Comment: well, it's not my issue but @MBH, anyhow I don't think that Completable is enough, as naturally you want value emission with network request

Comment: @yosriz If you want to update or delete a content on the server , you may are just interested by succes or error, in this case for example there are not value emitted to the client.

Comment: your'e right, but I understand that the request is to have data, but treat no data cases, maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: Ho maybe your are right and it's me who misunderstood.

Comment: may you please write an example of the map ? @Cochi

Comment: Sure , i will do that .

Comment: I have edited with a example, if you give me some details i can adapt it.

Comment: See this comment https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2242#issuecomment-300850574

Answer (score 1):

You can see my answer here:
[Querying single database row using rxjava2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489842/querying-single-database-row-using-rxjava2/42494369#42494369)
in short, you can use [Maybe](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#maybe) with RxJava2 or emit `Optional` of the expected result.

Comment: but Retrofit has its RxJava2 Extension which uses Observable only.

Comment: that's not true, Maybe is on the list of available types in the RxJava2 adapters, see your link